# About Ubuntu app showdown 2014

Tags: application-submission

Can somebody please tell me how to submit my app which is already published in the Ubuntu store, to Ubuntu App Showdown. [This page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/) says

> You must register your submission in the App Showdown form (to be put online soon).
>   When form will be online.

Comment: Soon... And I don't think that this is the right place where you will get a better answer to your question. But you can get live, real-time support from other app developers and Ubuntu engineers on Freenode IRC in the [#ubuntu-app-devel](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=ubuntu-app-devel) and [#ubuntu-touch](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=ubuntu-touch) channels.

Comment: How many apps I can submit for Ubuntu app showdown?

Comment: How many do you have?

Comment: Currently having two apps.

Comment: So, are you stuck after you added one?

Comment: No. I was asking is it legal to submit more than one app.

Comment: Don't ask, try. If problems appear, then ask.